# Can we use control the source formats/layout in DMExpress using environment variables?

Tags: etl

I am using DMExpress tasks to do taransformations on my business data. These business data come in multiple format/layout. I need to be able to use single task for transformation on multiple source layouts. Any DMExpress experts here??

Answer (score 0):

One way that I found out for doing transformation on multiple source layouts with the help of single task was by using the Dmexpress SDK to write the script for the task rather than building the tasks using the GUI task editor. SDK gives lot more flexibility compared to the GUI editor.

But if you are bound to GUI then there is a way around for this specific purpose. You should define a common name for the source layout. Only the source layout name is binded to the task but not the actual layout definition. So you can alter the layout definition while keeping the layout name constant to get a generic task.

Answer (score 0):

FYI- DMExpress is now called DMX (Syncsort changed the name about a year ago).

Do you have multiple different record types within a single file or is each type of record in a separate file?  Your question is not clear on this.

If they are in separate files, this is very easy, but you will need to create a separate DMX task for each file.  In each of these tasks, define one of the files as the source and create a record layout that matches the format of that file.

If they are in the SAME file, it is only a little more difficult.  You can split them into separate files by creating multiple targets and defining a named condition for each target using the SourceName() function (this function returns the name of the file that the current record came from).  Then you can process them as separate files (see above).  This works UNLESS you have a parent-child relationship going on between the different types of records in that single file.  If that is the case, please post some sample data and I can advise on how to handle it.